# Can pets and summons be used at the same time?

Tags: wakfu

Can we use pets and summons at the same time?

I was thinking of purchasing one, but I don't wanna spend the gils to then find out its not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Pets do not show in combat, they only give you more of one or many stats (Gemlin gives HP, Bow Meow gives lock, etc).

So, basicaly, yes, you can equip a pet, and, let's say as an osamodas, also use your summons in battle.